# WebAPI async call The client is disconnected because the underlying request has been completed

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

With the WebApi calls, randomly I get this message in live environment. It is async call. Does it mean the webAPI was not able to finish the request . I am calling using client ajax call. The entire trace looks like

> System.Web.HttpBufferlessInputStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 count)
>        at System.Web.Http.WebHost.SeekableBufferedRequestStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>        at System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFormUrlEncoded(Stream
>   input, Int32 bufferSize)

Comment: if you are calling to an async function and do not await, then the client will be disconnected. Make sure you have await in that method or if you do not want to await then provide a callback url and post process complete status to the callback page

Comment: Thanks .I am using jquery ajax call for the web api so I believe it should not be a issue.